# how to select a dropdown menu from a submenu in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, submenu

I am new to selenium and trying to select an option (Job Title) from sub menu (Job) where main menu is 'Admin' on OrangeHRM website.

my script clicks on admin but instead of mouse hover on "Job"and selecting "Job Title", it mouse hovers on another main menu called "Leave". Please help where am I going wrong.

```
sAdminMenu.click();
    System.out.println("Clicked on Admin menu ");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //job title selection
    Actions action = new Actions (driver);
    WebElement sAdminMenuJob = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='menu_admin_Job']"));
    action.moveToElement(sAdminMenuJob).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement sAdminMenuJobTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='menu_admin_viewJobTitleList']"));
    action.moveToElement(sAdminMenuJobTitle).click().build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

HTML

[image]

Comment: browser.find_element_by_xpath("YOUR_XPATH/option[text()='TEXT_OF_DROPDOWN_TO_SELECT']").click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
WebElement sAdminMenuJobTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='menu_admin_viewJobTitleList']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", sAdminMenuJobTitle);
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei for your answer but it doesn't work wither. Same issue as before, it mouse hovers on "Leave" main menu instead of sub menu "Job"

Comment: Could you please provide a link to website, or paste HTML code (also with `Leave` button.)

Comment: here is the link to the website. user details are on home page itself. http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/auth/login

Comment: I have added infos in the answer. You can use `JavascriptExecutor` instead

Comment: Happy to hear it, then you can mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button